# SimpleAudioEngine in Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Cocos2d 2.0 and below works with this:

```
  [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"SaveInMe.mp3"];
```

Which class plays music in Cocos2d 3.0 ?

Answer (score 6):

SimpleAudioEngine is not available in Cocos2d v3.0, use OALSimpleAudio

```
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"Effect.caf"];
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playBg:@"Game_BG_Music.mp3" loop:true];
```

Answer (score -2):

Imprt the audio engins and #import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
then play audio

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"themesound.wav"];
 //for stop audio
 [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
```